# Showing Snackbar with React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

First off, I'm completely new to React and Redux.

I'm having troubles with showing the `Snackbar` from `material-ui` as a notification panel whenever I've dispatched an event.

See mockup code for my example. The notification is not shown at all this way since `this.props.sending` in `App` component sets to `false` immediately when API call is successful.

Now if I skip the `SOMETHING_FULFILLED` dispatch everything seems to work fine. The `state.open` of the `Notification` component is set to `false` thanks to my `onRequestClose` function, but since the `this.props.sending` in my `App` component is still set to `true` - then every time the `App` component re-renders it shows the notification.

**Any idea how I would implement this correctly?**

I've got a `action` that looks something like this.

```
const doSomething = (data) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SOMETHING_PENDING',
      payload: { data }
    })

    apiCall.then((complete) => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'SOMETHING_FULFILLED',
        payload: { data }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

And my `reducer` looking like this.

```
const initialState = {
  sending: false
}

const SomeReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SOMETHING_PENDING': {
      return {
        ...state,
        sending: action.payload
      }
    }

    case 'SOMETHING_FULFILLED': {
      return {
        ...state,
        sending: false
      }
    }

    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}

export default SomeReducer
```

My `App` component connected to the store.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const storeData = (store) => {
  const data = {
    sending: store.Reducer.sending
  }

  return data
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Notification sending={this.props.sending} />
    )
  }
}

export default connect(storeData)(App)
```

And my `Notification` component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar'

class Notification extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { open: false }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.sending) {
      this.setState({ open: true })
    } else {
      this.setState({ open: false })
    }
  }

  closeNotification = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Snackbar
        open={this.state.open}
        message={'test'}
        autoHideDuration={4000}
        onRequestClose={this.closeNotification}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default Notification
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, it sounds like you have your Snackbar working properly, but it closes too quickly.  You'd like it to show but then auto-close itself 4 seconds later, even if the API call itself only took .5 seconds for example.  Is that correct?  If so, I believe you can simply skip re-rendering your component when the `state.open` is being changed from true to false (but still allow render when going from false to true):

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // Only re-render when snackbar is going from closed to open
  return !this.state.open && nextState.open;
}
```

Comment: This did it. Simple and neat. Thanks a ton, Jeff!

Comment: But what I do when I need to show snakbar on request success or failure !!